# Como faço para retornar as solicitações SNMP em sequência utilizando for() em node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, async, async-await, snmp

Estou criando um script que pega um Ip dentro de uma array de Ip's e executa uma consulta SNMP e retorna o nome do alvo. Desejo percorrer toda essa array e retornar em sequência as consultas com o nome do host que possui aquele Ip. Porém, o retorno é embaralhado e não é em sequência. Preciso executar o código e as respostas vim de acordo com a sequência de Ip's dentro array.

O código é o seguinte:

```
var snmp = require ("net-snmp");

/* Lista de Ip's */
var ips = ["172.16.8.1", "172.16.18.1", "172.16.16.1"];
           /* CPRM-1, HMUE, FUNTELPA_1.*/
/*  1.3.6.1.4.1.1916.1.13.2.1.3 -- OID do Protocolo EDP */
var oid = ["1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0", "1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6.0"];


for(cont = 0; cont <= 2; cont ++){
    /* cria a sessão */
    var session = snmp.createSession (ips[cont], "v1a1pe@RNPcom91");

    /* busca a solicitação */
    session.get (oid, function (error, varbinds) {
        /* Tratativa de erro */
        if (error) {
            console.error (error);
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < varbinds.length; i++) {
                if (snmp.isVarbindError (varbinds[i])) {
                    console.error (snmp.varbindError (varbinds[i]));
                } else {
                    /* Retorna o Nome do host que possui o IP */
                    console.log (varbinds[i].oid + " = " + varbinds[i].value);
                }
            }
        }
        /* Encerra a sessão */
        session.close();
    });

    /* Verificar interceptações */
    session.trap (snmp.TrapType.LinkDown, function (error) {
        if (error) {
            console.error (error);
        }
    });
}
```

O retorno é:

```
1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0 = HMUE
1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6.0 =
1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0 = CPRM-1
1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6.0 =
1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0 = FUNTELPA_1
1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6.0 =
```

A ordem correta dos Ip's é seria: CPRM-1, HMUE, FUNTELPA_1.

Tentei utilizar métodos `async/await` dentro de funções, mas não obtive nenhum resultado.

Não manjo muito desses métodos, estou procurando exemplos para entender melhor seu conceito.

Alguém sabe me dizer se estou no caminho certo?

Answer (score -2):

Sim, você está no caminho certo. Mas, pelo que pesquisei sobre a biblioteca que está utilizando (net-snmp), ela não possui nenhuma de suas implementações utilizando o assincronismo moderno (Promises), mas utiliza alguns callbacks - método antigo - quando precisa disso. Portanto, você terá de criar um módulo Facade para a lib; ou seja, criar uma "interface" para o acesso e execução dela e, a partir daí, aplicar as técnicas de Promises.

Dessa forma, ao montar o módulo consumidor - parte responsável por inicializar a lib -, você conseguirá utilizar métodos async/await, melhorando a performance e executando as operações de forma serializada como deseja.

Exemplo de como ficaria o Facade:

```
class NetSNMP {
  #session = null;

  createSession(target, user) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        this.#session = snmp.createSession(target, user);

        return resolve(this.#session);
      } catch (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
    });
  }

  getSession(oids) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        if (!this.#session) throw new Error('Invalid session');

        this.#session.get(oids, (err, varbinds) => {
          const varbindsLength = varbinds.length;

          if (err) throw new Error(err.message);

          for (let i = 0; i < varbindsLength; i++) {
            if (snmp.isVarbindError (varbinds[i])) {
              throw new Error(snmp.varbindError(varbinds[i]));
            } else {
              /* Retorna o Nome do host que possui o IP */
              const oid = varbinds[i].oid;
              const hostname = varbinds[i].value;
              const result = `${oid} = ${hostname}`;

              console.log(result);

              resolve(result);
            }
          }
        })
      } catch (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
    });
    
  }
}
```

Adaptando o seu código dessa maneira, ele passará a retornar Promises da execução da lib, por estar encapsulado. Assim, você conseguirá usar estruturas como o `for await...of`.